# Unable to fetch a response - Request library Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am unable to fetch a response from this url. While it works in browser, even in incognito mode. Not sure why it is not working. It is just keep running without any output. No errors. I even tried request headers by setting 'user-agent' key but again received no response

Following is the code used:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://www1.nseindia.com/ArchieveSearch?h_filetype=eqbhav&date=04-12-2020&section=EQ')
print(response.text)
```

I want html text from the response page for further use.

Comment: Perhaps you're getting a redirect, which has no text.  Browsers automatically follow redirects, but requests doesn't (unless you tell it to).  Try printing just `response` and see what you get.

Comment: He says he is getting no response at all, unless I misunderstood his question.

Comment: I did check the network tab, there were no redirects when i hit the link using chrome browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server is checking to see if you are sending the request from a web browser.  If not, it's not returning anything.  Try this:

```
import requests

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0'}

r=requests.get('https://www1.nseindia.com/ArchieveSearch?h_filetype=eqbhav&date=04-12-2020&section=EQ', timeout=3, headers=headers)

print(r.text)
```

Comment: No it is still not working. It triggers timeout error. I even increased the timeout to 10. Thanks for trying

Comment: I tested it on my end and it works.  I got the same issue you had with a timeout before I added the headers.  There is something going on here with the server.  No doubt the server is doing something else to prevent web crawling (like you're trying to do).    Have you looked for a robots.txt file (see https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/intro)?

Comment: Not found any robots.txt file on this link: https://www1.nseindia.com/robots.txt